# scrartcl: Remove page number on title page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, titles

I'm writing the abstract for my bachelor thesis. Therefore I use LaTeX.
Now I have the structure of my document, but it always prints me a page number on the page. It is only one page and instead of my title (abstract) und my abstract text there should be anything on the page.

The command `\pagestyle{empty}` should remove all header & footer, but it doesn't work

Here's my Script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,smallheadings]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

\typearea{12}
\pagestyle{empty}

\title{Abstract}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

...TEXT...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`\maketitle` sets the pagestyle to `\titlepagestyle`. This can be redefined to be the `empty` pagestyle by

```
\renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{empty}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,smallheadings]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

\typearea{12}
\renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{empty}


\title{Abstract}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

...TEXT...

\end{document}
```

Comment: In case you are also using `tocloft`, make sure to read http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137301/15107

Answer (score 1):

Another way is that: inserting 
`\pagestyle{empty}` and, eventually, `\thispagestyle{empty}` 
*after* `\maketitle`.

Comment: Welcome, that may work, but using the defined interface for robust changes is better. But i would avoid using `\pagestyle` here, as it goes on till changed, which can be missed easily.

Comment: This is a rather a comment