# tocloft package interfering with ToC page style?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, tocloft

I use the trick from [How to get header and footer over ToC, LoF and Nomeclature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42912/how-to-get-header-and-footer-over-toc-lof-and-nomeclature) to ensure that all pages have headers and footers, including the first page of the Table of Contents, except without headers and footers on the front page:

```
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

That works fine.  However, I then use the trick from [TOC Text - numbers alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/toc-text-numbers-alignment) to widen the space reserved for section numbers (so that section "10.10" doesn't cause overlapping text)

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
```

Adding the tocloft command seems to reverse the 'fancy page style' command, so that the ToC no longer has headers and footers.

Do these commands need to be in some specific order to work correctly?

Alternatively, is there some other (non-tocloft) way to fix ToC numbers and text that overlap?

Comment: thank everyone, the explication of add the package `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
` is correct. Add the result!!! thanks!!!![![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGqoY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGqoY.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `tocloft` package is loaded, the page style of pages in the ToC, LoT, and LoF is governed by the package's `\tocloftpagestyle` macro. Tocloft's default page style is `plain`. To change the page style of these pages to `fancy`, issue the command

```
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
```

---

**Addendum**, prompted by a comment by [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg): You can also achieve your objective by loading the `tocloft` package with the `titles` option:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

The manual of the `tocloft` package has the following to say about this option:

> The `titles` option causes the titles of the ToC, LoF, and LoT lists to be
>   typeset using the default LATEX methods. This can be useful, for example,
>   when the `tocloft` and `fncychap` packages are used together and the 'fancy'
>   chapter styles should be used for the ToC, etc., titles.

It turns out that the `titles` option is quite useful not only if the `fncychap` package is in use, but also if the `fancyhdr` package is employed.

Comment: Probably it's better to pass the `titles` option to `tocloft`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for pointing out the use of the `titles` option. I've augmented my answer to mention this possibility. I must confess that I had been vaguely aware of the option, but because the package's manual mentions it for use with packages such as `fncychap`, it hadn't occurred to me until now that the option may come in handy with other packages too, including `fancyhdr`.