# tocloft with cftaftertoctitleskip fails to change space below "contents"

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Here's a [not] working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} 

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\title{Hello world  \vspace{-0.5cm}} 

\begin{document} 

\maketitle 

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-100pt}
\tableofcontents

\section{A}

A stuff

\section{B}

B stuff

\end{document}
```

When I compile this multiple times, changing the value of `\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-100pt}` to various other values, I don't see any change in the space after the table of contents title.  Is there an obvious error in my script?

Comment: The `\cftaftertoctitleskip` feature gets broken by the `[titles]` option of `tocloft`.  That is because (see Mico's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137299/tocloft-package-interfering-with-toc-page-style) the `titles` option **purposefully** bypasses the `tocloft` mechanisms for setting the `toc`, `lof`, `lot`, etc.

Comment: I would hasten to add that the obvious solution is to load `tocloft` without the `[titles]` option, if you wish to use the `\cftaftertoctitleskip` mechanism.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that appears to be correct.  Consider posting that as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around, I discovered the root of the problem was the `titles` loading-option of `tocloft`.  Remove that option and it worked as expected.  Searching the site revealed this question, [tocloft package interfering with ToC page style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137299/tocloft-package-interfering-with-toc-page-style), and Mico's answer to it.

Specifically, Mico notes this:

> The manual of the `tocloft` package has the following to say about this option:
>
> > The `titles` option causes the titles of the ToC, LoF, and LoT lists to be
> >     typeset using the default LATEX methods. This can be useful, for example,
> >     when the `tocloft` and `fncychap` packages are used together and the 'fancy'
> >     chapter styles should be used for the ToC, etc., titles.

This very explicitly points to the problem and the solution as well.  The `titles` option is intended for use, when one wishes to use some of the `tocloft` features, but not actually set the `toc` using the `tocloft` features.  The solution?  remove the `titles` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} 

\usepackage{tocloft}

\title{Hello world  \vspace{-0.5cm}} 

\begin{document} 

\maketitle 

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-100pt}
\tableofcontents

\section{A}

A stuff

\section{B}

B stuff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ironically, the reason I had the titles option there in the first place was because I followed the advice of one solution you cited:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137299/tocloft-package-interfering-with-toc-page-style ... in the end I reverted to the non-titles version of the solution which worked fine.

Comment: @Steven Respectfully, removing the `titles` option is not a solution. There is a good reason why the OP passed the option to begin with, and the problem is not solved. You do not solve the problem, you simply *remove* it.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the `titles` option, which might be important in case you have to use `fancyhdr`.

I assume the purpose is to remove the vertical space before the first section title:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\title{Hello world}
\author{Zkurtz}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-\cftbeforesecskip}}
\tableofcontents

\section{A}

A stuff

\section{B}

B stuff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm ... maybe so.   Actually I think was trying to add space in that position, although I've since iterated too much to reconstruct exactly what I had.  I was playing with `\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{2pt}` and `\setlength\cftbeforesubsecskip{-3pt}` types of settings when I ended up with too little space between "Contents" and the contents.

Comment: This is a real solution, which does not involve removing the `titles` option. As a complement, I have added a proposal to specifically pass the value `-100pt`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify a vertical space after the toc title, simply use:

```
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\vspace{<whatever value you wish>}}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} 

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\title{Hello world  \vspace{-0.5cm}} 

\begin{document} 

\maketitle 

\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\vspace{-100pt}}
\tableofcontents

\section{A}

A stuff

\section{B}

B stuff

\end{document}
```

[image]