# ClassicThesis - more space after TOC title

Tags: classicthesis, titletoc

I work with the latest ClassicThesis package and realized the TOC shows my entries too close to the title "CONTENT". I would like to have some more space between the title and the first entry of the TOC.

[image: TOC Space under Title]

You can even see it if you run a very simple document based on the newest ClassifThesis package. This is so massive, I hardly understand what control commands are set. It has so many parameters! No chance for me to strip it all down to the one critical parameter... Over the last days, I tried to understand it how I could shift down the content of the TOC under its title. To do so, I tried adding

```
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{3em}
```

as well as

```
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{3em}
```

However, this gets just ignored... =(
I would be glad to receive any hint what to do. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you try `\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{3em}` ?

Comment: Thank you - I did try with \setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{3em} , however no impact visible. It seems to be ignored somehow.

Comment: Actually I had a look at this one and guess it might lead me to a solution... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323890/tocloft-with-cftaftertoctitleskip-fails-to-change-space-below-contents/323899   However, I just have no insight into the large ClassicThesis package to see where the remove the title option... ?

Comment: Please add a MWE so we can help, otherwise we're just shooting in the blind

Comment: @Christopher: No. Please provide some initiative and help the audience by creating *your own minimal example* that replicates the current behaviour. So, *you* should provide the "very simple document based on the newest `ClassicThesis` package".

Comment: @Werner: I was really thinking how I could do that. I see no way how I can strip down a massive package like the ClassicThesis into just some lines of code. The issue mentioned occurs even if you load the default ClassicThesis project from BitBucket and just compile it... but reducing this to the essence of the issue - no chance for me. Sorry for asking in this case ! I am far away from being an expert on Latex.

Comment: @Christopher: Do you [see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446507/5764) how small the example code is that replicates your behaviour (thanks to [`blindtext`](//ctan.org/pkg/blindtext))? This is listed in [the construction of a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764).

Comment: @Werner: Okey - got it. I was not aware you can setup MWE's this way and will have a closer look on that. Thank you for your support, it is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your document starts with a chapter instead a part, add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\vspace{\dimexpr\cftbeforepartskip-\cftbeforechapskip\relax}%
}}
```

to the preamble.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{classicthesis}[2018/06/03]
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\vspace{\dimexpr\cftbeforepartskip-\cftbeforechapskip\relax}%
}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\part{A Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Totally working fine for me. I digged deeper into your commands, especially the "dimexpr" which is new to me. Thank you so much - your help is awesome here on this forum. Respect !