# fancyhdr not working with wrapfigure on page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, wrapfigure

I am using `fancyhdr` to specify the header and footer of my document. Everything works fine until I try placing a `wrapfigure` environment on the page as below:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
  \begin{tocbox}\tableofcontents\end{tocbox}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Then, the page numbering goes to the default style with the arabic numbering at the bottom center of the page. If I remove the `wrapfigure` chunk, my custom header/footer shows up again...

Is there there a way to get the header/footer working while using `wrapfigure`?

Comment: You're much more likely to get help with something like this if you post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) compiliable as is. To help you, I'd need to test your code, but I don't know what packages you're using; I tried to guess, but have no idea where the "`tocbox`" environment comes from or how it's defined. I shouldn't have to guess; please post everything needed to replicate the issue.

Comment: Ahh found the culprit! It's actually the interaction between `fancyhdr` and `tocloft`. [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137301/268650) did the trick!