Three-section header
Consider the following (simplified) Latex code to generate a document.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[inner=2cm,outer=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespace
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-4em}   
\title{{\bf Discussion} }
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{-3cm}
\section*{Section a. Objectives}
XXX
\end{document}

I want to add a three-section header to EACH page of the document. The header should be as close as possible to the picture (graysh, italics, Times New Roman, 11 font). The footer should have just the page number at the centre, as it is now. Could you advise?


Use either [tag:scrlayer-scrpage] or [tag:fancyhdr] or [tag:titleps] to configure the page header and footer you want. There are already several examples in using these packages.

I have explored fancyhdr also looking at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers#Changing_headers_and_footers_for_%E2%80%9Cnon_standard%E2%80%9D_LaTeX_document_classes but it is too complicated for me.

Show what you've tried. And also explain, where the three parts of the header come from. For example, if would guess the left one is a static one. The right one may come from a \section*{ACRONYM}. The middle may also be static, manual or from a \part{…}. But these are only guesses and it is your job to make it clear — best explaining it on an example. And also tell us, whether the page header and footer should be the same on the page with the title, which would be very unusual.

Off-topic: Don't use old font commands like {\bf …}. Use either {\bfseries …} or (often better) \texfbf{…}. Also note, that \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is not needed with up-to-date LaTeX for a long time. And please also note, that geometry, setspace and titling are usually not need to show a problem with page header and footer. So please use them only, if needed.

And note, that all the recommended packages from my first comment have user manuals. So instead of just reading some third-party-information, I strongly recommend to read the user manual.

Explain where the three parts of the header come from: I am not sure what you are referring about. This is the screenshot of a word document.

I've already explained, what I mean: Do you want so set all three elements manually or do some of them correlate with another document element like a section title, a part number … So explain as exact as possible, how the three elements of the head should be filled. If not, I could only tell: use \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} and \ihead{left}\chead{middle}\ohead{right}. But don't blame me, if this is not the best solution.

Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31200/scrartcl-remove-page-number-on-title-page or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154870/how-to-use-maketitle-without-make-it-a-title-page-so-the-header-and-footer-woul

Because your question is quite unclear (see my comments about this) and seems to ask three questions (color, font, page header and footer), here is just an example that shows more or less the page header of your screenshot:
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,headings=small]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{newtx}% Font
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% Page header footer
\usepackage{xcolor}% Color
\let\raggedsection\centering

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{gray}}
\ihead{\textit{Applicant's last name}}
\chead{Part I}
\ohead{ACRONYM}

\begin{document}
\section*{Discussion}
\end{document}


However, I'm almost sure, that this is not the best possible solution. For example if the “ACRONYM” should refer to an element like \addsec{ACRONYM} on this page, it would be better to use the LaTeX mark mechanism and scrlayer-scrpage option automark or command \automark. See the scrlayer-scrpage chapters in the KOMA-Script user manuals for more information about page header and footer configuration. See the chapter about the main classes scrartcl, scrreprt, scrbook in the KOMA-Script user manuals for more information about \raggedsection and options sfdefaults and headings. See a LaTeX introduction for more information about \textit. See the xcolor user manual for more information about using colors.
A similar solution using standard class article would be:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtx}% Font
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% Page header footer
\usepackage{xcolor}% Color
\let\raggedsection\centering

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{gray}}
\ihead{\textit{Applicant's last name}}
\chead{Part I}
\ohead{ACRONYM}

\begin{document}
\section*{\centering\normalsize Discussion}% not the best idea but works for star variant
\end{document}



How to make it work on the first page with \maketitle?

@Star I've already asked, whether you want this in my comments to the question. Unfortunately, my inquiries have not prompted you to revise the question. :( As also already told: It is very unusual to use a page header on the page with the title, so I would not recommend it. But with KOMA-Script class you can add \renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{scrheadings} (→ the KOMA-Script user manuals) to the document preamble. With the standard class, you can try \AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{\thispagestyle{scrheadings}} instead.

@Star See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31200/scrartcl-remove-page-number-on-title-page
